# Why are my photographs saving as UNADJUSTEDNONRAW?

Tags: raw, file-transfer, raw-vs-jpeg

I am currently studying photography at sixth form and have recently done a few photoshoots with my Nikon D5300. Instead of uploading my photos at school onto the school system, I download them onto my MacBook Air and then copy them across to an external hard drive and one drive so that I can access them at home and school.

However, when I have been copying my photos across on to my external hard drive and one drive, they have been saving as UNADJUSTEDNONRAW_thumb_e00a.jpg rather than thumb_DCS_0469_1024.jpg, for example. All the settings are as they should be. I'm not sure if it's something to do with my MacBook.

Why is this was happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: How are you doing the copying?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Yes more info. Do you have the original files?  At what point did they change, on the mac or on the external drive or  the one drive ( what is one drive )  Can you compare the copies to the originals and see if the file size has been changed?

Comment: Which program/software/app do you use?

Comment: That looks like just the thumbnail. What are the main files saving as?

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are importing the photos to Apple's Photos app and then copy and pasting them out, rather than exporting or draging them.

I did a [quick screen recording](https://youtu.be/wRgKq0-I_Ag) (can we embed these? I feel like I should know)  to show the point: in this video you can see that dragging the photos out works, but copy and pasting gives the results you describe.

https://youtu.be/wRgKq0-I_Ag

Comment: I had the same problem because I was copy and pasting...doing an export solves the problem. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks for solving!